# Cannot set radio button value dynamically after second click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, radio-button, angular-forms

I have a button which is used to check or uncheck radio buttons dynamically. The problem is it works once and then if I decide to manually click on the radio button of the same group (another one of-course) it updates as expected. However, when I then try do dynamically adjust it to the previous value (with the button click) it doesn't apply that value anymore.

Here is the code

**html:**

```
<input type="radio" id="one" class="" formControlName="group" value="one" [checked] = "radioGroup.first" >
<input type="radio" id="two" class="" formControlName="group" value="two" [checked] = "radioGroup.second" >
<input type="radio" id="three" class="" formControlName="group" value="three" [checked] = "radioGroup.third" >
```

**.ts**

```
onRadioDynamicChange() {
this.radioGroup = { first: true, second: null, third: null };
}
```

So, it changes the first time I click on the onRadioDynamicChange, it checks the first radiobutton. Then I click on its sibling and then again on the onRadioDynamicChange and it doesn't check the first radioButton anymore, no action occurs.

**EDIT**

Here is the behaviour: [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srfwdq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: where r u calling onRadioDynamicChange ?

Comment: In my html,  button (click)="onRadioDynamicChange"

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use radio buttons with `NgModel` like in [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/RadioControlValueAccessor#how-to-use-radio-buttons-with-form-directives)?

Comment: @barbsan I suspect it's because his form is a reactive form, and mixing reactive forms with model driven forms isn't something desirable?

Comment: @eugensunic Instead of value="one" try [value]="one"

Comment: @rdd good point, but my main point was that `ngModel` was based on `value` not `checked` attribute. I suspect that `checked` set to `null` doesn't remove `checked` attribute from `input`

Comment: I cannot use ngModel because of the form. Does anyone know why my view doesn't update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also tried what you have done Auqib Rather, that was my first solution of the problem, but it still not working great, it happens same isssue as the op. First time working, next time will not update.

I found a workaround, try this  :

```
  <div class="container">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" (click)="radio = 'one'" id="one" class="" value="one" [checked]="radio == 'one'">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="two" (click)="radio ='two'" value="two" [checked]="radio == 'two'">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="three" (click)="radio ='three'" class="" value="three" [checked]="radio == 'three'">
        <button (click)=' onRadioDynamicChange()'>Click Me</button>
    </div>
```

ts :

```
  onRadioDynamicChange() {
        this.radio = "one";
  }
```

But I didn't know why the first aproach is not working as expected. If someone know the reason i'll be glad to know about it.

Comment: @eugensunic,Nico  can you provide a fiddle on the same issue ? will look into it

Comment: I'll do it a little bit later.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept your solution. It is really amazing that my approach doesn't work I guess you are not allowed to explicitly set other radio buttons to null/false. You should only take care of the target one

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use object of any type  as you used in 
   [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srfwdq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html] you should use example 'radioGroup' object as radioGroup:any={}
so that you can add property  to it and in html use optional if you are not sure about object property weather or not it is present as
'radioGroup?.first', 'radioGroup?.second'and 'radioGroup?.third'

you should use like this and make sure only one of object 'radioGroup' is true at one time 
  in ts.

```
  export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Angular';
    radioGroup:any={first:false,second:false,third:false};


    onRadioDynamicChange() {
      this.radioGroup.second =false;
      this.radioGroup.third=false;
      this.radioGroup.first =true;
    }

  }
```

in html

```
<form >

<input type="radio" id="one" name="a"  value="one" 
[checked] = "radioGroup.first" >First
<input type="radio" id="two" name="a"  value="two" 
[checked] = "radioGroup.second" >Second
<input type="radio" id="three" name="a"  value="three" 
[checked] = "radioGroup.third" >Third


<button type="button" 
(click)="onRadioDynamicChange()">first</button>

  </form>
```

it will work definitely

Comment: It doesn't work, and I should not be using the name attribute since I have from the angular form--> formControlName

Comment: do you have imported these modules insiide app.module.ts
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';

Comment: hadn't I had them imported, my app would throw errors at compile time... Yes they are there... I'll try to create a stackblitz later in the afternoon gmt+2